# Change Letters in a string to phrases (eg D to Delta, )

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently writing a small ATC program. I'm using a text-to-speech function, and would like it to read letters as in the aviation alphabet. For example,A is spoken as Alpha, B as Bravo, and so on.

At the moment, I've used a find and replace method shown, but I feel that this is inefficient and unnecessary.

```
lblDialogHidden.Text = txtCallsign.Text.Replace("D", "Delta, ");
lblDialogHidden.Text = txtCallsign.Text.Replace("E", "Echo, ");

// this converts the Letters to Aviation Alphabet phrases, so they are spoken rather than sounded out, or spoken as a complete word such as DEG.
```

This works, but as I said, it seems like the worst way possible of doing what I would like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off processing the whole string in one go like this:

```
      public string ToPhonetic(string source)
      {
         var sb = new StringBuilder();
         foreach (var ch in source.ToUpper())
         {
            switch (ch)
            {
               case 'A':
                  sb.Append("Alpha, ");
                  break;

               case 'B':
                  sb.Append("Bravo, ");
                  break;

               default:
                  sb.Append(ch);
                  break;
            }
         }

         return sb.ToString();
      }
```

Fill in the missing phonetic codes and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Dictonary` in that case:

```cs
public static void Main()
    {
            Dictionary<char, string> dDict = new Dictionary<char, string>() { { 'a', "Alfa" }, { 'b', "Bravo" } };
            string result = string.Join(" ", "abc".Select(x => dDict.Select(p=>p.Key).Contains(x) ? dDict[char.ToLower(x)] : x.ToString()));
            Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

output:

```
Alfa Bravo c
```